# HTMLのボタンからPythonスクリプトを用いてSeleniumを実行する方法について

Tags: python, selenium

Python+Seleniumで特定のサイトにログインするスクリプトを作成しました。
Brythonを使ってHTMLで作成したページからボタンを押してこのPythonを実行したいのですがうまくいきません。Seleniumを使わずに、HTML+Brython+Pythonでブラウザからボタンを押すとHelloと表示されるものまで作成できましたが、
from selenium import webdriver
の行を追加するだけで動かなくなります。調べたところ古い情報ですがBrythonはJavaScriptのエミュレータなのでSeleniumは動かせないというようなものを目にしました。この解決方法はありますでしょうか。

HTMLで作成したボタンからSeleniumを実行してウェブサイトにログインできればどのようなソフトウェアを用いたものでも構いません。
現在別の考えている解決方法はTomcatでservletまたはJSPとして行う方法ですが、web系のプログラマではないのでフロントエンドやバックエンドなどの言葉が曖昧に分かる程度で全くの未経験です。
よろしくお願いします。

環境
・Windows 10
・Selenium
・Brython
・Python 3.7

Comment: フロント（HTML側）からサーバのAPIを叩くと、サーバの中でPythonが実行され、結果をフロントに返すという構成はいかがでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。調べたところFlaskでHTMLのページを表示→ボタンを押す→サーバー内のPythonを実行という感じになるでしょうか。フロントに返すものは成否くらいで良いのですがBrythonやHTMLからPythonを直接実行できず困っておりました。Flaskの方法を試してみたいと思います。

Comment: 試してみたところ無事Flaskでやりたいことができそうです。助かりました。

Answer (score 1):

今回の事例では、

> Python+Seleniumで特定のサイトにログインするスクリプトを作成しました。

とのことでしたので、これを活用する提案をコメントしたところ、回答者の方が自力で解決なさったので、回答の形でまとめます。

## 今回解決できた構成

Flaskでビュー（HTML）を返し、ボタンクリックなどでFlaskにリクエストを送信することで先述の特定のサイトにログインするスクリプトを実行し、成否をフロントに返すという構成を作成、無事動作したようです。

なお、Flask以外でのWebフレームワーク（Djangoなど）や、 `http` モジュールを使うことでも同様の構成は可能ですが、Flaskはシンプルで、作りやすいので適切な判断であるといえます。